# Public User Function to change Values

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I would like to add a button to allow the public user to save simple true/false boolean values in their session and change things in the template according to those decisions. I think there are quite a few scenarios where something like this applies, like light/dark theme choice, "are you over 18" age queries or GDPR/Privacy stuff, where google analytics scripts need to be loaded only after the users decision.

For example I when I want to add a theme choice for public users.

This are my fields in my apostrophe-palette-global:

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-palette-global
module.exports = {
  paletteFields: [

    {
      name: 'backgroundColorLight',
      label: 'Light Background',
      type: 'color',
      selector: [
        '.sections-content.light'
      ],
      property: 'background-color',
    },
    {
      name: 'backgroundColorDark',
      label: 'Dark Background',
      type: 'color',
      selector: [
        '.sections-content.dark'
      ],
      property: 'background-color',
    }
  ]
};
```

Create the template is pretty straightforward...

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/pages/home.html

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
  
  <div class="sections-content
// Define data scene only for user?
    {% if data.user.lightTheme %} 
      dark
    {% else %}
      light
    {% endif %}
  ">
    {{ apos.area(data.page, 'sectionArea', {
      limit: 1,
      widgets: {
        'sections': {
          pageShadow: data.page.shadow,
          addLabel: 'Add Sections',
          editLabel: 'Change Sections',
          controls: {
            movable: false,
            removable: true,
            position: 'top-left'
          }
        }
      }
    }) }}
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

But I wasn't able until now to add a button which is accessible for everyone ( anon, user, admin ) and in this case would change the value of `data.user.lightTheme` where this value is only an example because I don't know how to store values in the public session, it won't be that easy for shure because I have to store the values via cookie or `window.localStorage`.

But is there an apostrophe way to do that and if it is, do you have some examples for that? That would be really helpful...

Comment: Can you more fully explain how you want this part to work? "so admin can add palette fields choose colors"

Comment: I've updated the question now to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe doesn't have a preference for reading/writing a browser storage endpoint, you'll have to roll your own with custom front end scripts that read/write and maintain your state.

Below are some more detailed notes based on your code samples, you might not need this if you have a pretty good grasp on what to do when the answer to your original question is "no" :)

1. The way you're handling theme styles via palette seems good, although I would alter your selectors to follow something higher in the DOM, like

```
paletteFields: [
  {
    name: 'backgroundColorLight',
    label: 'Light Background',
    type: 'color',
    selector: [
      '.light .sections-content'
    ],
    property: 'background-color',
  }
]
```

This way you only have to attach your theme class to some upper wrapper, possibly `body`

2. If you're relying on the user's `localStorage` the server isn't going to know about it, so it won't be part of anything passed into your nunjucks templates. You'll need to handle this from a normal front end script. If you haven't pushed a custom script the [quick how-to is here](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/core-concepts/front-end-assets/pushing-assets.html#configuring-javascript-for-the-browser). Once you get your custom script pushed you'll want to read and write from your storage of choice (cookie, localStorage, sessionStorage). The basic flow might look something like:

- Read the storage and look for the user's theme preference. If nothing is found, set or assume a default.
- From your script, set the theme as a class on some high up wrapper in the DOM that all your style-able components will inherit from.
- If no preference was found initially, present the user with some custom UI that lets them make a choice. (this part could be infinitely specific)
- Write the user's choice to back to storage for the next page load.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you mean, I'll give it a try. thx very much...